# How do you convert a fluent nHibernate dynamic property mapping to the NH 3.2 mapping by code equivalent

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping in fluent nHibernate:

```
public CustomFieldsMap()
{
    Schema("schema");
    Table("table");

    Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Column("id"));
    DynamicComponent(x => x.Fields, c =>
    {
        ...insert code here...  
    });
}
```

This works fine (with the real code in obviously).

What I cannot work out is what the equivalent is (if there is one yet) in the mapping by code feature introduced in nHibernate 3.2?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide dynamic component template.

```
Component(x => x.Fields, new
{
    IntField = 0,
    RelationField = default(Related)
}, dc =>
{
    // dynamic component members mappings
    dc.Property(x => x.IntField);
    dc.ManyToOne(x => x.RelationField);
    // etc.
});
```

See [this article](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html) for examples and explainations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use RegisterDynamicComponentMapping?